# Need to add each number 0-x to end of line?

Tags: c#, list, stream

I'm making an app and I'm almost done. I just need to know how I can streamread a txt list and foreach line, add numbers 0-x (x will be the number the user puts in the textbox) and add it to a list. So basically, it would be like this

You import a list with 'dog' on one line, 'cat' on another, and 'fish' on the third. You type '5' into the textbox. the app puts all this into a list:

```
dog1
dog2
dog3
dog4
dog5
cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
fish1
fish2
fish3
fish4
fish5
```

thanks!

Comment: can you show the code you have?

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show us the code that doesn't work as intended.

Comment: I did not have code to do this. I had code that picked a random number 0-x, and it didn't do it for each number. it did dog1,cat2,fish3 kinda thing but random. I decided this way would be a lot easier and better and does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below should work for you.  I assume you can acquire the `count` value on your own.

```
var animals = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.txt"); //new[] {"dog", "cat", "fish"};
var count = 5;

var merged =
    from a in animals
    from n in Enumerable.Range(1, count)
    select a + n;

foreach (var m in merged)
    Console.WriteLine(m);  //act on each however you want
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read a text file with [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx). This gives you an array you can iterate over with [`foreach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx).

In this `foreach` loop you can perform another loop from 1 to the number the user entered. [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19.aspx) comes in handy for converting the string the user entered into a number C# can do something with. For the actual iteration you can use a [`for` loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

You can then add each item to a list.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example for reading each line in a filestream here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4y2dch9.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<string> GetThings(string fileName, int count)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in lines)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                result.Add(item + i.ToString());
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] inputList = File.ReadAllLines("yourFile.txt");
        List<String> listOfThings = new List<String>();
        foreach (string i in inputList)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < 5; k++)
            {
                listOfThings.Add(i + " " + k.ToString());
            }
        }
```

then after that, you can print out the list like this:

```
foreach (string outp in listOfThings)
 {
   Console.WriteLine(outp);
 }
```

output:

```
some value 0
some value 1
some value 2
some value 3
some value 4
some other value 0
some other value 1
some other value 2
some other value 3
some other value 4
```